# Apollo GraphQL - Import .graphql schema as typeDefs

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

With graphql-yoga you can simply import your schema by doing the following: `typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql'`. Is there a similar way of doing so with apollo-server-express?

If there isn't, how does one import the typeDefs from an external `.graphql` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way of doing this by using [graphql-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-import) which does exactly what I need. See sample code below:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import'
import Query from './resolvers/Query'

const typeDefs = importSchema('./src/schema.graphql')
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
        Query
    }
})

const app = express()
server.applyMiddleware({ app })

app.listen({ port: 4000 })
```

**

**UPDATE: graphql-import v0.7+**

**

`importSchema` is now async and should be handled as a promise. Just wrap it in a `async` function and simply `await` it:

```
async function start() {
    const typeDefs = await importSchema(".src/schema.graphql")
}
```

Comment: Current version of graphql-import return a promise which results in a error!

Comment: @OtmanBouchari Just wrap it in an async function and await the result :)

Comment: Seems like the package `graphql-import` has been deprecated in favor of `graphql-tools` according to the announcement [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-import)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `makeExecutableSchema` to pass in the `typeDefs`. Something like this:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import mySchema from './src/schema.graphql';

const app = express();

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [mySchema],
  resolvers: {
    ...
  },
});

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlExpress({ schema })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more recent response, following the top of the tutorial here [link](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/3-a-simple-mutation/) one can move the schema to a new file called schema.graphql and then import "fs" and "path" and input in the file so now it looks like:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'),
    'utf8'
  ),
  resolvers,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated: 06/2023**

Using [@graphql-tools/merge](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/schema-merging#manual-imports)

```
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge')
const clientType = require('./clientType')
const productType = require('./productType')
 
const types = [clientType, productType]
 
module.exports = mergeTypeDefs(types)
```