# How to load query from .graphql file with angular and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am working on an app with Angular and Ionic. As a backend I have a node server running ApolloServer with Neo4j (using grandstarter.io). On the client-side I currently have a file called queries.ts where I have defined my graphql queries like this:

```
supplierByName = (value) => {
    const query = gql`
    {
        Supplier(filter: {name: "${value}"}) {
            name
        }
    }
    `;

    return query;
};
```

I am using apollo so I am doing like this to run my graphql query

```
this.apollo.query({
                query: this.queries.supplierByName(supplierName)
            })
            .subscribe(....)
```

Now, due to not liking to have my graphql queries as strings I would like to have my queries in a .graphql file directly. Better tooling when working directly in a graphql file and honestly its mostly because the queries hurt my eyes right now :)

I would like to have it like this(file: queries.graphql):

```
query supplierByName($value: String) {
 Supplier(filter: { name: "$value}" }) {
    name
 }
}
```

then when I execute graphql query with Apollo I would like to do something like this:

```
 import supplierByName from './queries.graphql'
 .....
 this.apollo.query({
                query: supplierByName(supplierName)
            })
            .subscribe(....)
```

and use it with apollo in some easy way.
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385525/apollo-graphql-import-graphql-schema-as-typedefs) answer but from what I can gather it has to do with ApolloServer. I want to simply parse the graphql queries on the client. I found [this](https://dev.to/open-graphql/how-to-resolve-import-for-the-graphql-file-with-typescript-and-webpack-35lf) article that came close to what I need but it also has to do with ApolloServer. I am using Angular 8.1.2

All the examples in the Apollo documentation with angular shows examples with the way I currently have built my queries with strings and the use of gql (graphql-tag).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First add webpack loader to your webpack config according to [apollo document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/recipes/webpack/).

```js
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
  }
]
```

You not must use double quotation in .graphql file for variables. So your queries.graphql must be like this:

```js
query supplierByName($value: String) {
 Supplier(filter: { name: $value }) {
    name
 }
}
```

And the last you must pass variables to your query as follows:

```js
import supplierByName from './queries.graphql'
 .....
 this.apollo.query({
  query: supplierByName,
  variables: {
    value: supplierName, // your value
  }
})
  .subscribe(....)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. +1. But I am having problems with the typescript compiler still. It still doesn't recognize supplierByName. I believe there are more config to be done in the tsconfig.json file? I am trying to solve it using your answer and what is described here https://dev.to/open-graphql/how-to-resolve-import-for-the-graphql-file-with-typescript-and-webpack-35lf

Comment: You're welcome. For support .graphql file in typescript you must declare type  definition. First add `"typeRoots": ["src/@types","node_modules/@types"]` to your `tsconfig.json`. When create `src/@types/graphql.d.ts` file and write [this content](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mohsen89z/1bfd1af5ffcd8bf401aad88e0d4165fc/raw/dc83876690cb131dfed2552934dd74b0194b2492/graphql.d.ts) to it. If solved your problem please verify my answer.

Comment: I have been trying this but I have run into several problems that has to do with adding custom webpack loaders. Will mark this as accepted as soon as I can confirm...

Comment: Can i help you? Where is your problem with webpack loader?

Comment: Posting a new question about this. Will give you link soon. Dasted dard nakone ;)

Comment: OK, i'm at your service. Khahesh mikonam.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800757/webpack-loader-for-graphql-tag-not-loading-in-angular-8

Comment: Found the problem with webpack. Confirmed that this works. Thank you again.